# Armature changes mesh weirdly

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

I am new to blender, so I will do many mistakes while writing this question. So please forgive me for that[image]

As you can see here when I move the armature the mesh of only hand should change, but weirdly it also changes mesh of stomach too.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkiWBSSuxLw&t=644s) tutorial to make this

Here is my model file : [Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1clpUVblJDqyUtMw9c6yr58xGermKWjHD/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: As Blunder points out, it comes from the bad scaling of your object, in *Object* mode you need to apply the *Scale* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*). Once done, as it has inverted the normals, you need to go in *Edit* mode, select all and recalculate with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

As for the hand moving the stomach vertices, remove these vertices from the vertex groups you want:

[image]

As for your second object, select the faces that are all along the axis and remove them:

[image]

Now select the inner meshes with some <kbd>L</kbd> (you can also selet one face then with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> it will select the whole mesh):

[image]

Remove them:

[image]

Also don't forget to enable the *Clipping* option in the *Mirror* modifier.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134847/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-armature-changes-mesh-weirdly).

Comment: Your answer worked.. thanks for that... But, I created another model and did exactly same thing which you told but  in this one, the problem of mesh changing wierdly when we change the armature of the hand still exists.. [Please check the model file here](https://pasteall.org/blend/0d7cae36d07940619dd3acfa581d7fa3)

Comment: not sure what you mean, first thing you should not create thickness, unless you have a good reason (?), plus it has created some faces all along the axis

Comment: @moonboots is there any way to fix it now?

Comment: select and remove the faces all along the axis, then with L select the inner mesh and remove it, it should work

Comment: I've editeds my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: @moonboots omg you are a genius!!!!! it worked thanks!!!! how the hell do you know so much about blender????

Answer (score 4):

I looked into it. As @moonboots pointed out. You need to recalculate your normals. You have to go into edit mode and select all your faces:

[image]

After that, parrent it to the armature using the Automatic Weights.
It should work after that.

[image]

Hope that helps